# KDE System monitor grid scale reset

Tags: 18.04, kde, system-monitor

I am using KDE System monitor version 5.16.5
I can open it and navigate to 'system load' tab.
There is graph that shows CPU History, Network history etc.

I want to tweak graph properties, let say I want to change from % to Mb for Network history.
When I do right click on graph pop up shows 'Properties', when I click 'Properties' 'Plotter settings' shown where I can specify min and max value for the graph.

But no way to selet % scale. I can use only numbers. When I choose 0 to 100 it is shows only 0 to 100, instead of real percentage.

Even worth, after editing this setting I can't revert to initial system monitor state.

Is there a way to choose system monitor graph scale properly?

Here is screenshot of system monitor, where Network History and CPU History shown as 0-100 without any data displayed.

[image]